# recursion of main

Tags: c++, recursion

I read some where that recursion of main() is not allowed in c++ but when i tried it ran without any error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int i=10;

int main()
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        cout<<i;
        return 0;
    }
    i--;
    main();
}
```

Comment: Many things are not allowed in C++ despite not giving errors. C++ is a document, a specification. A compiler is an implementation of that specificiation. The specification can say things like "You must not call `main` explicitly`. But the implementation can choose what should happen if you do it *anyway*

Comment: How can you tell it ran without an error? Since the specification doesn't say what *should* happen in this case, on what basis can you describe what *did* happen as what should have happened or not? (If, for example, you think you should have gotten an error, then the fact that you didn't get the error you should have gotten *is* an error, right?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `main` explicitly is undefined behavior, anything can happen (including appear to work).

#### C++03 3.6.1

> 3) The function main shall not be used within a program. [...]

The compiler (as all undefined behavior goes) is not required to provide a diagnostic, nor is the runtime required to crash.

Comment: This is a flat prohibition, not undefined behavior. The usual convention in the standard is to say "no diagnostic required" if the intention is to not require a diagnostic (i.e. undefined behavior).

Comment: @PeteBecker: Is there really a distinction? Isn't what happens if you violate a prohibition UB?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - yes, there is a distinction. Undefined behavior simply means that anything goes. Violating a requirement **requires a diagnostic**, for which compilers typically issue a warning or an error. Granted, having issued the diagnostic, the compiler is free to do anything at all, but it's the diagnostic that makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not valid, and a conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic. Having done so, the compiler is free to do anything at all, including generating an executable file that runs and does something like what you expect it to do.

Note that g++ doesn't seem to issue a diagnostic, but the EDG compiler (through comeau online) does.